# Best way to archive old data from SQL Azure?

Tags: migration, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-data-warehouse

I have an app that stores event data. We use SQL Azure. Right now it's very expensive. Over $800/month to host. Once the event is over, I want to move the data to a DB that has a lower cost. Thus this will keep my SQL Azure usage lighter, and allow me to downgrade to a cheaper plan.

What is the best option?

1. Move data to a SQL Server Standard Edition (on-prem)
2. Move data to an MySQL Server (on-prem)
3. Use a new NoSQL DB?

The end-goal is to update our API, so it will pull data from both DBs in the results.

Comment: PostgreSQL is not an option?

Comment: Can you provide more info on your Azure SQL tier? Is it provisioned or serverless? vCore or DTU purchasing model? It may be that changing your Azure SQL tier/type might be enough - for example a Gen 5, 4-core Provisioned DB comes in ~$800 p/m for 800 GB storage. Switching to serveless and using 4-core compute for a total of 48 hours over a month costs ~$200 p/m, so when your usage drops, you could save substantial cost simply by moving to serverless.

Comment: As already stated, there are a lot of parameters to this. Are you in the situation where you need to have a higher tier purely because you have a lot of data? If you considering non-PaaS but you are already in Azure I suggest an Azure VM rather than an on-prem one. I don't know what currency you're talking here but a 4CPU 32G 1Tb disk Ubuntu is US$248 a month. While paused it is $65 a month. Not sure what the SQL licencing is but this has $0 all over it. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/sql-server-standard-linux/